# The DevOps Starter does not exist or you do not have permission to access it

Tags: azure

I'm owner of my organisation but I'm getting this message in `DevOps Starter` when I try to see resources that others have been created.

> The DevOps Starter does not exist or you do not have permission to
>   access it.
>   [image]

Any idea why and how to deal with it?

Comment: I'm Owner and Co-Administrator on Azure Portal, Project Administrator on the DevOps board and Project Collection Administrator for the DevOps organization. Still getting this trash message trying to see the DevOps starter object in Azure Portal.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be one of those cases where you might need to create a new Devops account , this happens because of synchronization between the devops account and the devops starter.

You can find similar solution [**here**](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/362023/the-devops-project-does-not-exist-or-you-do-not-ha.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps:

1. Delete all projects and related components
2. Create a new project in DevOps
3. Perform the operation again in DevOps pipeline

*Make sure you save your source code before deleting the project*

Hope this should solve your problem :)

Comment: Hi Pratik, deleting our DevOps project is not an option. This is a year old project with multiple developers, several complicated pipelines and a lot of history.